# RSpec: Stub chains with arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

Just wondering if/how arguments can be passed in rspec stub chains. To give an example, suppose I have the following action:

```
def index
  @payments = Payment.order(:updated_at).where(:paid => true)
  @bad_payments = Payment.order(:some_other_field).where(:paid => false)
end
```

In my controller spec, I'd like to be able to stub out both methods and return different results. If only the `@payments` field were in the action I'd use something like

```
Payment.stub_chain(:order, :where) { return_this }
```

But of course, that will return the same value for `@bad_payments`.

So - in short, how do I include the `:updated_at` and `:paid => true` as stub conditions?

Comment: Look [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/CUmVm3uERew) if it help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use this:

```
Payment.stub_chain(:order, :where).with(:updated_at).with(:paid => true) { return_this }
```

Comment: This doesn't really work. Seems like the `with` argument gets ignored. Try changing it to something which should fail and will will still pass.

Comment: @Zubin is right, I tried changing the with to arbitrary values, and no error is thrown, meaning the with calls are ignored.

Comment: This is deprecated in the new rspec version.

Answer (score 17):

With `rspec > 3` use this syntax:

```
expect(Converter).to receive_message_chain("new.update_value").with('test').with(no_args)
```

instead of `stub_chain`.

Read more about message chains [in the documenation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains). And [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers) is the argument matchers documentation.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The first call to `with` is ignored.

Comment: Yes I also got the same issue. args within the first with() method is not getting tested. Did u guys found any solution?

Comment: Nothing about `with` for `receive_message_chain` in the mentioned docs.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as the current excepted solution is deprecated in the new rspec version.

Answer (score 16):

You can use nested stub block. The block can accept arguments, and the return value is used as function return value.

I use `tap` because `stub` does not returns the callee. The **mock** created by `double` is returned as the result of method `order`, which `where` method is stub again.

```ruby
Payment.stub(:order) { |order|
  double('ordered_payments').tap { |proxy|
    proxy.stub(:where) { |where|
      [order, where]
    }
  }
}

Payment.order(:updated_at).where(:paid => true)
# => returns [:updated_at, {:paid => true}]
```