# Mocking chain of methods in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

There are a chain of methods which gets a `user` object. I am trying to mock the following to return a `user` in my `Factory Girl`

```
@current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
```

I can mock the object up until the `call` method but I'm stuck at mocking the `result` method

```
allow(AuthorizeApiRequest).to receive(:call).and_return(:user)
```

Comment: I have found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003445/rspec-stub-chains-with-arguments?rq=1 ,it may be useful for you

Answer (score 38):

I found I need to use [`receive_message_chain`](https://rspec.info/documentation/3.8/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ExampleMethods.html#receive_message_chain-instance_method)

So this worked for me.

```
allow(AuthorizeApiRequest).to receive_message_chain(:call, :result).and_return(user)
```

Comment: This works in some cases, but notice the "Warning" in the doc page: "Chains can be arbitrarily long, which makes it quite painless to violate the Law of Demeter
in violent ways, so you should consider any use of receive_message_chain a code smell."

They recommend using `double` or `double_instance`, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922393/2233856.