# How to add auth token to each http RSpec test header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, http-headers

I'm having trouble trying to authenticate a request spec. How would I pass a valid auth token in the header of each http request? Is my approach below the correct?

tweets_request_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Tweets API', type: :request do
  before do
    @tweets = create_list(:tweet, 10)
    @tweet = @tweets.first
  end

  describe 'GET /tweets' do
    before { get '/tweets', { "Authorization": *some sort of token*} }

    it "returns tweets" do
      expect(json).to_not be_empty
      expect(json).to eq(10)
    end

    it "is a successful http request" do
      expect(response).to have_http_response(200)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my code for the authentication controller, as well as the modules that help with generating and decoding the auth tokens that are passed in the http headers.

authentication_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_request

  def authenticate
    command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password])

    if command.success?
      render json: { auth_token: command.result }
    else
      render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :authorized
    end
  end
end
```

authorize_api_request.rb

```
class AuthorizeApiRequest
  prepend SimpleCommand

  def initialize(headers = {})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def call
    user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def user
    @user ||= User.find(decoded_auth_token[:user_id]) if decoded_auth_token
    @user ||= errors.add(:token, 'Invalid token') && nil
  end

  #decode the auth token and retrieve the user id
  def decoded_auth_token
    @decoded_auth_token ||= JSONWebToken.decode(http_auth_header)
  end

  #retrieve auth token from header
  def http_auth_header
    if headers['Authorization'].present? 
      return headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
    else
      errors.add(:token, 'Missing token')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: include the links you are using to build this

Comment: I've been following this link to add user auth: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api

Comment: thanks good luck happy new year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some Code Extracts copied from the [the official pluralsight page](https://web.archive.org/web/20171215095913/https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api#4LKQzekUjYf808zC.99)

the endpoint to authenticate is in `config/routes.rb`

```
post 'authenticate', to: 'authentication#authenticate'
```

which executes this action. The action returns the token if you correctly authenticate.

```
def authenticate 
   command = AuthenticateUser.call(params[:email], params[:password]) 
   if command.success? 
      render json: { auth_token: command.result } 
   else 
      render json: { error: command.errors }, status: :unauthorized 
   end 
end
```

In rspec you have two options, you either mock this method or create a factory.

The concept of `token based` authentication is that once authenticated the user will have a token and by providing this token he will be able to access the functionalities only reserved to users

The request

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"example@mail.com","password":"123123123"}' http://localhost:3000/authenticate
```

gives in response the token

```
{"auth_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0NjA2NTgxODZ9.xsSwcPC22IR71OBv6bU_OGCSyfE89DvEzWfDU0iybMA"}
```

if you include in the header the token, the request will not trigger an authorization error

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJleHAiOjE0NjA2NTgxODZ9.xsSwcPC22IR71OBv6bU_OGCSyfE89DvEzWfDU0iybMA" http://localhost:3000/items []
```

so before doing your get request, include in the request header the token

```
request.headers['Authorization'] = auth_token
get :your_action
```

How to provide a correct value of `auth_token`?

You will need to [mock](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) the method `authenticate_request` in `ApplicationController`, as it is called `before` the `action`

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
 before_action :authenticate_request
  attr_reader :current_user

  private

  def authenticate_request
    @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
    render json: { error: 'Not Authorized' }, status: 401 unless @current_user
  end
end
```

I believe you should mock this line of code, to avoid receiving an authentication error.

```
@current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
```

so I would write the specs somethind like this

```
user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
allow(AuthorizeApiRequest).to receive(:call).and_return(user)
# request.headers['Authorization'] = auth_token # this is not required anymore the authentication is skipped
get :your_action
```

I quote [pluralsight](https://web.archive.org/web/20171215095913/https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api#4LKQzekUjYf808zC.99)

> By using before_action, the server passes the `request headers` (using the built-in object property request.headers) to `AuthorizeApiRequest` every time the user makes a request. Calling `result` on `AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers)` is coming from `SimpleCommand` module where it is defined as `attr_reader :result`. The request results are returned to the `@current_user`, thus becoming available to all controllers inheriting from `ApplicationController`.

You can read more about mocking at

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

Comment: Any idea why the mock line is giving me:
 Failure/Error: @current_user = AuthorizeApiRequest.call(request.headers).result
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `result' for #<FrontendUser:0x007f9aa3668b28>  # FrontendUser is my own custom class.

Comment: Solved it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571911/mocking-chain-of-methods-in-rspec