# How do I 'expect' a chain of methods using Rspec where the first method takes a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I have a method call in a ruby model that looks like the following:

```
Contentful::PartnerCampaign.find_by(vanityUrl: referral_source).load.first
```

Within the models spec.rb file, I'm trying to mock that call and get a value by passing in a param. But I'm having trouble figuring out the correct way of calling it.

At the top of my spec.rb file I have:

```
 let(:first_double) { 
   double("Contentful::Model", fields {:promotion_type => "Promotion 1"}) 
 }
```

Within the describe block I've tried the following:

```
expect(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive_message_chain(:find_by, :load, :first).
                                       and_return(first_double)

expect(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive_message_chain(:find_by, :load, :first).with(vanityUrl: 'test_promo_path').
                                       and_return(first_double)

expect(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive_message_chain(:find_by => vanityUrl: 'test_promo_path', :load, :first).
                                       and_return(first_double)
```

As you can probably guess, none of these are working. Does anyone know the correct way to do this sort of thing? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, I prefer not to use stub chains, as they are often a sign that you are violating the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). But, if I had to, this is how I would mock that sequence:

```
let(:vanity_url) { 'https://vanity.url' }
let(:partner_campaigns) { double('partner_campaigns') }
let(:loaded_partner_campaigns) { double('loaded_partner_campaigns') }

let(:partner_campaign) do
  double("Contentful::Model", fields {:promotion_type => "Promotion 1"}
end

before do
  allow(Contentful::PartnerCampaign)
    .to receive(:find_by)
    .with(vanity_url: vanity_url)
    .and_return(partner_campaigns)

  allow(partner_campaigns)
    .to receive(:load)
    .and_return(loaded_partner_campaigns)

  allow(loaded_partner_campaigns)
    .to receive(:first)
    .and_return(partner_campaign)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do. Notice that I split the "mocking" part and the "expecting" part, because usually I'll have some other `it` examples down below (of which then I'll need those `it` examples to also have the same "mocked" logic), and because I prefer them to have separate concerns: that is anything inside the `it` example should just normally focus on "expecting", and so any mocks or other logic, I normally put them outside the `it`.

```
let(:expected_referral_source) { 'test_promo_path' }
let(:contentful_model_double) { instance_double(Contentful::Model, promotion_type: 'Promotion 1') }

before(:each) do
  # mock return values chain
  # note that you are not "expecting" anything yet here
  # you're just basically saying that: if Contentful::PartnerCampaign.find_by(vanityUrl: expected_referral_source).load.first is called, that it should return contentful_model_double
  allow(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive(:find_by).with(vanityUrl: expected_referral_source) do
    double.tap do |find_by_returned_object|
      allow(find_by_returned_object).to receive(:load) do
        double.tap do |load_returned_object|
          allow(load_returned_object).to receive(:first).and_return(contentful_model_double)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

it 'calls Contentful::PartnerCampaign.find_by(vanityUrl: referral_source).load.first' do
  expect(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive(:find_by).once do |argument|
    expect(argument).to eq({ vanityUrl: expected_referral_source})

    double.tap do |find_by_returned_object|
      expect(find_by_returned_object).to receive(:load).once do
        double.tap do |load_returned_object|
          expect(load_returned_object).to receive(:first).once
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

it 'does something...' do
  # ...
end

it 'does some other thing...' do
  # ...
end
```

*If you do not know about ruby's `tap` method, feel free to [check this out](https://medium.com/aviabird/ruby-tap-that-method-90c8a801fd6a)*

Comment: I found that this is especially useful when testing the Sequel gem's dataset chain calls to fetch data eg. `DB[:table].select(:column).where(id: 1).all`. If done the traditional way, you have to use a lot more lines mocking the doubles before running tests and then returning those doubles in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refactor the chain in two lines like this:

```
model    = double("Contentful::Model", fields: { promotion_type: "Promotion 1" }) 
campaign = double

allow(Contentful::PartnerCampaign).to receive(:find_by).with(vanityUrl: 'test_promo_path').and_return(campaign)
allow(campaign).to receive_message_chain(:load, :first).and_return(model)
```

Then you can write your spec that will pass that attribute to `find_by` and check the chain.